# Laravel : [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a laravel application where I have already create all the migration file. But when I tried to run the

```
php artisan migrate
```

command, I saw the following Error :

> ```
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'atom.users' does
>   n't exist (SQL: select exists(select * from `users`) as `exists`)
>
>   [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'atom.users' does
>   n't exist
> ```

I tried to update the composer and migrate:rollback But same Error I'm getting whenever I run the commands.Besides that there is no error with the .env files as well.I couldn't find what's the Error, if any one could help me to find the problem ..Thank you.

Here is my user table migration file :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create the atom database?

Comment: Yes .. I do have a database named atom

Comment: run command 'composer dump-autoload'  and try again..

Comment: I tried to run the command, But it's showing the same error .

Comment: first check modal  user.php is created  or not..?

Comment: Yup it's there in App\ directory

Comment: check DB connection from `.env` and from `config/database.php` - then restart server

Comment: .env is OK..I've already checked that.
same as config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

here's my history on the migration of user.

php artisan make:auth
php artisan make:model User
php artisan make:model User --migration
php artisan migrate:install
sudo  php artisan migrate:install
sudo php artisan make:migration
sudo  php artisan make:migration users

Btw, your migration file seems ok, hope this will help you

If it doesnt, try to "fake" some data in db table, and try again...

Answer (score 0):

Run: `php artisan clear-compiled` then run your migration again.